# Rails 2 to 3 routing question

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Im using the book railsspace but its made for rails 2 ive ran in to a bit of a snag the rails 2 routing looks like this

```
map.connect 'profile/:screen_name', :controller => 'profile', :action => 'show'
```

how do i make it work for rails 3 routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
match 'profile/:screen_name' => 'profile#show'
```

To learn more, read [this guide](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/) on EngineYard.